# Is it possible to redirect the page with PHP after an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a website where I want to provide an option for users, if they click on a table's rows, they get regirected to another page (based on the contect of the table row).

So what I'm doing is basically collecting the data with jQuery and POSTing that to a PHP file. In my PHP file I'd like to do the redirecting using `header('Location: ***')`.

Is it a correct way to do this? Because this way, the ajax request does not gets anything returned, no success, no nothing, it get redirected before that.

So is it a path that I could use, or should I come up with another idea?

Comment: AJAX expects a response.  If you bounce out of the page at the server side, AJAX won't get a response.  You shouldn't be using AJAX.  Whatever you intend to do with that AJAX call needs to be done as a simple POST to the PHP file.

Comment: You can return redirect path via Ajax and the do the redirect with JS

Comment: You could always do the redirect in javascript after the AJAX returns success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. If you work with jquery, and your ajax call responds with a json like this:

```
{
    success : true, 
    redirect_to : "http://www.google.com"
}
```

that in php means

```
<?php echo json_encode([
    'success' => true,
    'redirect_to' => 'http://www.google.com',
]);
```

then your ajax caller can do the dirty job:

```
$.get('/your/path', function (json) {
    if(json.success) {
        document.location.href = json.redirect_to;
    }
}, 'json');
```

My two cents.

Answer (score 4):

No.

A redirect tells the client that the resource they just requested can be found elsewhere.

The page that was previously loaded which contains that JavaScript is not the resource that the Ajax request is asking for. Something will be returned though—it should get the resource that you redirected to (which will be available in `xhr.responseText` (assuming the same origin policy doesn't interfere and that you get a `200 OK` response at the place you are redirecting to)

If you intend to always redirect, then don't use Ajax.

If you intend to sometimes redirect, then you'll need to put the URL in the *body* of the response, parse it with JavaScript and then assign it to `location`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the answer, its clear now. I would like to redirect the visitor always, however, how is it possible to do that in a table without using Ajax? I basically want to get the `id` from the row and when the visitor clicks on the row, they should land on `example.php?id=XXXXX`. This is why I wanted to use Ajax in the first place. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put a link in one of the cells. Add an click event handler to the row that checks `event.target`, finds the link descendant, gets the href, and assigns it to `location`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot redirect with PHP, however you can easily redirect with the response of your ajax call.

refer to: `window.location.replace(...)`

Answer (score 0):

> I basically want to get the id from the row and when the visitor clicks on the row, they should land on example.php?id=XXXXX

You can do so entirely from PHP. When you generate the table, in each row (whose id we'll call `XXXX` to follow your example) you can include a link to `example.php?id=XXXXX`, or an `onclick` event for the whole row that executes `window.location.href = 'example.php?id=XXXXX';`. So your table might look like:

```
...
<tr onclick="window.location.href = 'example.php?id=1234';">
  <td>1234</td><td>some value</td><td>some other value<td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="window.location.href = 'example.php?id=1235';">
  <td>1235</td><td>some value</td><td>some other value<td>
</tr>
...
```

It could be done a little nicer by generating the rows with javascript and using event listeners, but this should work.